# What is the cardinality of the power set $P(A \cup B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cardinals

Let $A = \{1, 3, 5\}$ and $B = \{3, 4, 5\}$ be sets.

> What is the cardinality of the power set $P(A \cup B)$?

If i'm not mistaking isn't it all the possible combination of these two:
$\{\}, \{1,3\}, ...$.

Comment: There was a previous answer which has been deleted that said 4. However my teachers note says 16 is the cardinality. So... It shouldn't be that difficult, i just want to know

Comment: x @ABCCode: That previous answer misread $A\cup B$ as $A\cap B$ and therefore got a wrong result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A \cup B = \{1,3,4,5\}$. The cardinality of the power set of a set of order $n$ is $2^n$. You should be able to calculate the cardinality then.

Comment: ahh, just so i get it what does the cardinality represent? and the power set, is that all the possible combination?

Comment: The cardinality of a set is the number of elements in the set. And yes you are right: The power set is all the possible combinations of the elements. See [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set)

Comment: 1) In this context (for finite sets) the cardinality is just the number of elements in the set. 2) The power set of a set is the set of all subsets of that set.

Comment: There are two possibilities for each element when making a subset: either it's in or it's out. Since $A \cup B$ has four elements, that means there are $2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2$ possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

$A\cup B=\{1,3,4,5\}$, so $$P(A\cup B)=\{\varnothing, \{1\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{1,5\},\{3,4\},\{3,5\},\{4,5\},$$

$$\{1,3,4\},\{1,3,5\},\{1,4,5\},\{3,4,5\},\{1,3,4,5\}\}$$

I provided the explicit power set to let you know what it is. Now you can count how many elements it has.

But you don't have to write out the power set to know its cardinality. $$|P(X)|=2^{|X|}$$

To prove it, consider strings of bits of length $|X|$: $$\underbrace{00\cdots 00}_{|X|},\, \underbrace{00\cdots 01}_{|X|},\ldots,\, \underbrace{11\cdots 11}_{|X|}$$

There are $2^{|X|}$ such unique strings. We can imagine they correspond to all the subsets of $X$ as follows:

Each bit corresponds to the respective element in $X$ in a way that if the bit is $0$, the element is not in the subset, and if the bit is $1$, the element is in the subset.

Comment: You've got $\cup$ and $\cap$ mixed up. $A \cup B=\{1,3,4,5\}$.

Comment: @alexqwx I've edited it.